# Swift : Player audio file from another class file

Tags: ios, swift

First of all, I just want to let you know I'm a newbie in iOS programming ;)

I would like to know if the following scenario is possible or which way I need to update my code to make it work.
I would like to play an audio file located in the **player class file** within the **ViewController file**.
I added the file "test.wav" to the root of project.

### My problem

When I play the sound by tapping a button, the program can't find the sound file. I have the following error message: 
**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)**

### Main swift file: ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player1: Player!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func playAudio(sender: AnyObject) {
        player1.playAudioFile()
    }

}
```

### Class file: Player.swift

```
import Foundation

import AVFoundation

class Player {

// Variables

    var vc: ViewController!
    var audioFile: AVAudioPlayer!


// Initializer

    init (){

    }

// Methods

    func playAudioFile() {

        if audioFile.playing {
            audioFile.stop()
        } else {
            audioFile.play()
        }
    }

// Intialize ViewController

    init (vc:ViewController!) {

        // Set path for the attack sound

        let audioSnd = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "wav")
        let audioFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioSnd!)

        do {

            try audioFile = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioFileURL, fileTypeHint:  nil)
            audioFile.prepareToPlay()

        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.debugDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

### More information

My program has a class "Player", with subclasses such as "Human" and "Monster".
By default, my class player has some audio files for attacks, dying, etc. 
Under some conditions, the "player" can become a human or a monster and get custom attack and dying sounds.

Thanks a lot for your help! ;)

Comment: You didnt initialize the player variable. Add: `player1 = Player(self)` to the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Actually, the original code is more complete for Player class.
For example:     
init (name: String){
        self._name = name
        self._fighterSpr = UIImage (named: "unknown")!

    }

But I get the same problem, anyway... :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dejan, I got it work. I'm going to update my code to so I can declare player1 that way in the viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you initializing you player with a `viewController` ? You dont need that.

**Change the `Player` class to:**

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class Player {

    // Variables
    var audioFile: AVAudioPlayer!

    // Initializer
    init() {
        // Set path for the attack sound

        let audioSnd = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "wav")
        let audioFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioSnd!)

        do {

            try audioFile = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioFileURL, fileTypeHint: nil)
            audioFile.prepareToPlay()
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.debugDescription)
        }
    }

    // Methods
    func playAudioFile() {

        if audioFile.playing {
            audioFile.stop()
        } else {
            audioFile.play()
        }
    }
}
```

**And your `ViewController.swift` to:**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player1: Player!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Note, that you need to initialize the player1 variable
        player1 = Player()

    }

    @IBAction func playAudio(sender: AnyObject) {
        player1.playAudioFile()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful, btw `import AVFoundation` is no need from `ViewController ` because you have isolated Audio operation in a single function. Before I didn't use the global `player1` instead initializing it `player1 = Player()` in func `playAudio` directly, then the sound is not played in simulator, weird.

Answer (score 0):

Swift is functional programming, so it is way better to separate the audio operation and viewController into different file/class. Then they could be reused in any scenarios.

### Audio part

```
import AVFoundation

class AudioPlayer {
    // Singleton to keep audio playing anywhere
    static let shared = AudioPlayer()
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    private init() {}
    
    func play(url: URL) {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
            
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            guard let player = player else { return }
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
        } catch {
            print("error occurred")
        }
    }
}
```

### ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func playAudio(sender: AnyObject) {
        let audioSnd = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "wav")
        // don't use force unwrap
        guard let audioFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioSnd) else { return }
        // call the shared instance here
        AudioPlayer.shared.play(url: url)
    }
}
```